# if mod(Z) = 1 and arg of z is $\theta$ then what is the argument of 1+Z/1-Z

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question says if mod(Z) = 1 and arg of z is $\theta$ then what is the argument of 1+Z/1-Z ?
I started assuming z=e^i$\theta$ then arg of Z is $\theta$

1+Z=e^i$\theta/2*$(2$\cos\theta/2$)

1-Z=2$\cos\theta/2$*e^i($\pi+theta/2$)

wht next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

WLOG let $z=\cos2y+i\sin2y$

$$\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}=\dfrac{1+\cos2y+i\sin2y}{1-\cos2y-i\sin2y}=\dfrac{2\cos^2y+2i\sin y\cos y}{2\sin^2y-2i\sin y\cos y}$$

$$=\dfrac{2\cos y(\cos y+i\sin y)}{-2i\sin y(\cos y+i\sin y)}=i\cot y$$

Alternatively,

$$\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}=\dfrac{1+e^{2iy}}{1-e^{2iy}}=-\dfrac{e^{iy}(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})}{e^{iy}(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})}=-\dfrac{2cos y}{2i\sin y}=?$$

Comment: bt the question remains wht will be the argument of this complex no. on the complex plane i appreciate ur efforts and understand the concept better now but my query stil remains unanswered

Comment: @PrateekChauhan,,What is the argument of $X+iY$?

Comment: i already said in the question its $\theta\

Comment: @PrateekChauhan, Answer in term of $X,Y$

Comment: look doesn't the arg come out to be pi/2 or -pi/2 as the no. icottheta would lie on Y axis

Comment: i mean i cot(theta)